# Linked list refuses to work with dynamiclly allocated buffer but works with static allocation

Tags: c, dynamic, linked-list

I've tried making a linked list with a dynamic allocated buffer but it just screws the program and exit.

for some reason, the program works perfectly with static buffer which is more perplexing to me.

I've checked that the memory allocation in fact does allocate and checked that the size of the memory is appropriate.

```
typedef struct game_node {
    char* title;
    char* genre;
    int year;
    float rating;
    struct game_node* next;
    struct dlc_node* dlc_head;
}GameNode;

typedef struct dlc_node {
    char* title;
    float price;
    struct dlc_node* next;
}DLCNode;

typedef struct {
    GameNode* head;
}GameLinkedList;
```

This is the function in which it gets stuck.

```
GameNode* GameAdd(){
    GameLinkedList *gm;
    char *buffer = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    
    GameNode *newNode = (GameNode*)malloc(sizeof(GameNode));
    if(newNode == NULL){return NULL;}
    newNode = gm->head;

    //Get Input from user

    printf("Game Title - ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    
    newNode->title = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    
    if(newNode->title == NULL){
        free(newNode->title);
        free(newNode);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    strcpy(newNode->title,buffer);
    //stops after this strcpy
    
    
    printf("Game Genre - ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    
    newNode->genre = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    if(newNode->genre == NULL){
        free(newNode->genre);
        free(newNode->genre);
        free(newNode);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(newNode->genre,buffer);
}
```

Comment: Where does `GameLinkedList *gm;` point to on the line `newNode = gm->head;`?

Comment: Just briefly reviewing your code yourself for a few minutes will reveal a lot of oddities... like, how can it ever make sense to call free() twice in a row with the same argument. Or to free() something you know is equal to NULL. And so on.

Comment: @mch it points to struct game_node from GameLinkedList to create the first chain of the linked list.

Comment: No, it does not point there. Between these 2 lines there is no assignment to `gm`. It is unitialized and dereferencing it will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your compiler should show some warnings about using variables without assigning a value. If not, increase warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",buffer);` This is dangerous. You should always provide a length limit for reading input: `scanf("%255s",buffer);`

Comment: @Lundin the second one was obviously an oversight, but my thought was that it might have allocated previously  won't be freed an create a memory leak.

Comment: Why do you sometimes `return NULL` and sometimes use `exit(1)` if you don't get more memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253308/discussion-between-rani-giro-and-gerhardh).

Comment: Do not edit the question after it has received comments/answers. It invalidates them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GameLinkedList *gm;
...
newNode = gm->head;
```

Problem: `gm` is used uninitialized in the assignment to `newNode`.

Aside:

- Check the return of `malloc(3)`.
- Don't cast the result of `malloc(3)`. `malloc(3)` and family returns a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. Casting only serves to clutter one's code.
- Don't pass `NULL` pointers to `free(3)`, or the same argument twice. The former is not an error per se, but the latter is sure to result in one.
- Use a field-width specifier with `scanf(3)`. Or Consider using `fgets(3)` instead.